# Do DispatchQueue threads get cleaned up if NSApp.terminate is called?

Tags: swift, macos

If I have a delayed code execution in my app:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(20), qos: .background) {
    //code
}
```

Do I need to cancel this or do anything specific in AppDelegate if NSApp.terminate is called before the job is run or is running? Do GCD threads automatically get cleaned up when the app exits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an application terminates, the operating system will automatically clean up all of its in-memory resources, including queues and threads. There's nothing you need to do to stop this task.